Unable to insert data to Kafka topic in Apache Flink using Upsert Kafka Connector in Python
I am working on building Apache Flink pipeline where source is SQL server CDC, and sink is Upsert Kafka, everything looks fine until when executing insert I got error of
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig
I am using Apache flink's Table API in Python.
This following way I am adding required jar files into my pipeline
jar_files = [
    "lib/mssql/flink-sql-connector-sqlserver-cdc-3.1.0.jar",
    "lib/mssql/mssql-jdbc-12.8.1.jre11.jar",
    "lib/postgresql-42.6.0.jar",
    "lib/flink-connector-jdbc-3.2.0-1.19.jar",
    "lib/flink-connector-kafka-3.4.0-1.20.jar",
    "lib/kafka-clients-3.8.0.jar"
]


jar_urls = [f"file://{CURRENT_DIR}/{jar_file}" for jar_file in jar_files]

table_env.get_config().get_configuration().set_string(
    "pipeline.jars",
    ";".join(jar_urls)
)

following is my kafka Sink
PARTICIPANT_SINK_DDL = 
    create table participant(
        people_id   BIGINT ,
        date_of_birth   TIMESTAMP ,
        date_died   TIMESTAMP,
        race_code varchar(10),
        ethnicity_code varchar(10),
        marital_status_code varchar(10),
        education_code varchar(10),
        employment_code varchar(10),
        participant_type_code varchar(10),
        gender varchar(10),
        PRIMARY KEY (people_id) NOT ENFORCED
    )
    WITH (
        'connector' = 'upsert-kafka',
        'topic' = 'participant',
        'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'localhost:9092',
        'key.format' = 'json',
        'value.format' = 'json'
    )


And this is how I am inserting data into my kafka topic
table_env.execute_sql('''insert into participant select 
                        PEOPLE_ID
                        ,DOB
                        ,date_died
                        ,(select distinct code_value from code where lower(trim(code_description)) = lower(trim(RaceID)) and code_type = 'RACE_TYPE'   )
                        ,(select distinct code_value from code where lower(trim(code_description)) = lower(trim(EthnicID)) and code_type = 'ETHNICITY_TYPE'  )
                        ,(select distinct code_value from code where lower(trim(code_description)) = lower(trim(MaritalStatus)) and code_type = 'MARITAL_STATUS_TYPE'  )
from PEOPLE 
''').wait()


